# Samsung Galaxy S4 crashing randomly with Xposed Framework installed

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, crashes, xposed-framework

I am on a rooted Galaxy S4. Software version 4.4.2. I have the xposed framework 2.6.1 installed. I am getting random crashes every few minutes-hours with it installed, with, or without modules. I dont get a popup error message. I just get the one vibration, followed by two short vibrations a few seconds later. I have tried asking elsewhere, I have tried different versions of the framework, I have uninstalled and reinstalled. Nothing has worked. I know it is xposed because as soon as I uninstall it I get no crashes.

The logcat messages says:

```
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14620)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2258)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:663)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-02 16:13:23.677 E/DatabaseUtils(894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```